# I have a problem with my last average calculation ( Reading file and storing values into arrays )

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE *in;
    float day[365],sup[365],mich[365],huron[365],erie[365],ont[365],stclr[365]; 
    int i,j;
    float year; 
    float sup_sum,mich_sum,huron_sum,erie_sum,ont_sum,stclr_sum;
    float sup_avg,mich_avg,huron_avg,erie_avg,ont_avg,stclr_avg; 
    int counter = 0; 


    in = fopen("C:\\Users\\TEMP.DESKTOP-O4G383R.000\\Desktop\\CPS Term Project\\term_proj_data.txt","r"); 

    while ( !feof(in) )
    {

    for( i = 0; i < 2920; i++)
    {//outer for loop   

    for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {//inner for loop 

    if (j == 0)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &year);

    if (j == 1)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &day[i]);

    if (j == 2)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &sup[i]);

    if (j == 3)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &mich[i]);

    if (j == 4)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &huron[i]);

    if (j == 5)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &erie[i]);

    if (j == 6)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &ont[i]);

    if (j == 7)         
    fscanf(in, "%f", &stclr[i]);

    }//inner for loop 

    }//outer for loop 

    }

    printf("%.2f", stclr[5]);

    /*--------------Calculating averages----------------------*/

    //lake Superior 
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    sup_sum += sup[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    sup_avg = sup_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake Superior temp avg:%f", sup_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    //lake Michigan 
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    mich_sum += mich[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    mich_avg = mich_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake Michigan temp avg:%f", mich_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    //lake Huron 
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    huron_sum += huron[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    huron_avg = huron_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake Huron temp avg:%f", huron_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    //lake Erie  
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    erie_sum += erie[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    erie_avg = erie_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake Erie temp avg:%f", erie_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    //lake Ontario   
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    ont_sum += ont[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    ont_avg = ont_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake Ontario temp avg:%f", ont_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    //lake St.Clair    
    for (i = 0; i < 365; i++)
    {
    stclr_sum += stclr[i]; 
    counter++;
    }
    stclr_avg = stclr_sum / counter; 

    printf("\n\n Lake St.Clair temp avg:%f", stclr_avg);
    counter = 0; 

    return 0;
}
```

The whole idea of my program is to read values from a txt file and store them into arrays. Then I must calculate the average temperature for each lake for 365 days. Everything is working fine for me except that the last average temperature gives an incorrect value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oIJ8.jpg)

I am not quite sure what is causing this. I am no expert in C. I am a student learning the language right now.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where have you narrowed the problem down to?

Comment: `float sup_sum` and all the other accumulators are not initialised to `0.0`. And `while ( !feof(in) )` combined with no input error checking is almost guaranteed to duplicate the final data / break the array. Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I tried removing the last for loop that calculates the temperature average for Lake St. Clair and putting it into an identical program (without other for loops) and it results in a correct value. Then, I put the last for loop back and removed any other for loop. When any one for loop is removed, the correct values are displayed, but when the number of for loops is the same as it is currently, the St.Clair Lake average temperature shows the incorrect value. I have not been able to successfully fix this.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much! This fixed my problem :) Although, may I ask why the first few averages displayed correctly even though they were not initialized to 0.0?

Comment: That's fine but did you really re-write the `feof` thing in that space of time?

Comment: Well, **** happens, that what happened. That's like asking why you didn't have to pay the train fare, when you didn't fare the train fare.

Comment: No, I meant to the average calculation problem. I will rewrite my loop.

Comment: Do **not** use a bare `fscanf(in, "%f", ...);`, test the return value of `fscanf()` to determine is the scan succeeded.  [ref](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)